# Kotlin's Higher-Order Functions in Java project

Tags: java, lambda, interop, kotlin, higher-order-functions

I have a function that has a function type as a formal parameter:

```
fun doSomething(code: () -> Boolean) = false //package function in TestKt.class
```

I've tried calling it in Java, passing in a lambda:

```
//Java class, in Java project
class Demo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestKt.doSomething(() -> false);
    }
}
```

But I get the error:

> Cannot infer functional interface type

It works when the Java class is in a Kotlin project, but not in a Java project. I haven't had problems with anything else while using classes from Kotlin in my Java project, such as using kotlin methods typed with `kotlin.Boolean` and working with `vararg` parameters.

**Question**

How do I properly call the `doSomething` function from a Java project?

Comment: What version of kotlin are you using so I can try expand upon my answer? :)

Comment: @ConnorSpencerHarries How do I check? I know my version isn't the most current, I've been having problems installing the newest update via IDEA, so I figured I'd let it ride til I bumped into a problem

Comment: If you open your module settings (right click your project in the project explorer) you should see a "Libraries" button, hit that and you should see the version of the Kotlin runtime you're using, IntelliJ may try to use the same version for compiling if you are not using Maven or a similar tool.

Comment: @ConnorSpencerHarries It doesn't specify the version ([picture](https://gyazo.com/149e2a3afec89fd5df58a19362552486)). I checked there before asking :s Do you think it has to do with my other project not depending on the Kotlin library? It seems like it would be a reason, but it's strange how using things such as `kotlin.Boolean` works just fine without the dependency. The environment I'm working in does not support external dependencies

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the following code

```
fun doSomething(method: () -> Boolean) = method()
```

And the following java

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(MainKt.doSomething(() -> true));
    }
}
```

It works just fine.

Answer (score 3):

I threw your code into a module in my project and it built just fine, though this may be a side effect of me using multiple modules as the kotlin is *always* compiled to java before the java projects can touch it.

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] mesh-parent ....................................... SUCCESS [1.718s]
[INFO] mesh-common ....................................... SUCCESS [13.141s]
[INFO] mesh-controller ................................... SUCCESS [8.217s]
[INFO] java-so-project ................................... SUCCESS [1.121s]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 24.558s
[INFO] Finished at: Thu Jan 07 20:21:30 GMT 2016
[INFO] Final Memory: 55M/341M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

Process finished with exit code 0
```

If you are using maven (with mixed kotlin and java in a single module) then you may be required to add the following to your POM:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
    <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>process-sources</phase>
            <goals> 
                <goal>compile</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <phase>process-test-sources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>test-compile</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

<strike>I'm not sure if such a solution exists for gradle.</strike> If you don't use a dependency manager then you should be able to work around this by invoking the kotlin compiler and then `javac`.

Without the workarounds mentioned I couldn't compile it either.

**Edit:** It appears Gradle requires no workaround as demonstrated [here](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin-examples/blob/master/gradle/mixed-java-kotlin-hello-world/src/main/java/demo/HelloWorld.java).

Comment: Kotlin sources are not compiled to Java, they're compiled to JVM bytecode directly (as Java sources are)

Comment: I know, I just worded it like that for the sake of digestibility.